# In android studio.Why when I run the app on my android device, the Views getting flipped horizontally?

Tags: android, android-studio

This code is for an example.In the "preview" tab in android studio, I see "A" in the left side, and B in the right size.However when I install the app to my android device I see "A" on the right side and "B" on the left side.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A"
        android:textSize="16sp/>

  <LinearLayout/>




  <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">

      <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="B"
         android:textSize="16sp/>

  <LinearLayout/>


<LinearLayout/>
```

Comment: Check your language setting on device. You are probably using a Right to Left Language on device while the Android Studio default is Left to Right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this article to see if the "Force RTL layout direction" option is turned on:

http://lifehacker.com/enable-androids-secret-right-to-left-layout-if-youre-le-1676267178